# SQL - Finding the earliest and latest non null value in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I need to find the earliest and the latest (Non Null) value of a column in a Group By statement.

Example:

Bob has multiple purchase records for a given day. I need to find Bob's first and last purchase in a grouping of records for that day.

- Bob bought pencils on 1/1/2014 12:00pm
- Bob did not make a purchase, but checked in on 1/1/2014 1:00pm
- Bob bought paper on 1/1/2014 2:00pm

So I have three records, one with a null value indicating no purchase was made.

I've used the following query to retrieve all employee records where there are more than one for a given day.

```
SELECT nameid, 
       Min(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10)) AS Date, 
       Count(*)                                  AS Duplicates 
       -- <<<Get Earliest Purchase And Latest Purchase From each group Where Not Null>>>
FROM   employee 
GROUP  BY nameid,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 111) 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
```

If I just retrieve the earliest date, using MIN(mDateTime) it is possible the value will be null. I need the earliest non null value and the latest non null value from each grouping.

Thank you for your direction and patience.

**WARNING**: This is a hypothetical rendition of the code I'm actually editing. The scenarios, naming conventions, and completeness is abbreviated to simplify and highlight the issue.

Comment: I've edited your question to replace the `WHERE` with `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` clause(among others) since i think that the wrong syntax was not part of your issue, agreed?

Comment: When you say "So I have three records, one with a null value indicating no purchase was made." what field is null (what is the name of that column holding the null value)? mdatetime?

Comment: Do you want to count all the duplicates or just the purchased ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all comments, the answer is:

Consider this build scheme:

```
create table employee  (nameid varchar(100), mdatetime datetime, purchase varchar(200))
insert into employee values ('Bob', '2014/01/01 12:00pm', 'books')
insert into employee values ('Bob', '2014/01/01 01:00pm', NULL)
insert into employee values ('Bob', '2014/01/01 02:00pm', 'pencil')
```

The query that will get the first and last no null purchase and select the purchase field is:

```
SELECT A.nameid, A.Date, A.MIN_DATE, B.purchase MIN_PURCHASE, A.MAX_DATE, C.PURCHASE MAX_PURCHASE
FROM (
  SELECT nameid, 
   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10) AS Date, 
   Min(case when purchase is null then null else mDateTime end) MIN_DATE,
   Max(case when purchase is null then null else mDateTime end) MAX_DATE,
   Count(*) AS Duplicates 
 FROM   employee A
 GROUP  BY nameid,  CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10) 
 HAVING Count(*) > 1 
) A
INNER JOIN employee B
  on A.nameid = B.nameid
  and A.MIN_DATE = B.mdatetime
INNER JOIN employee C
  on A.nameid = C.nameid
  and A.MAX_DATE = C.mdatetime
```

Look the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dc3eb/4/0)

Comment: I need the earliest and latest NOT NULL purchase. Wouldn't this simply give me the first NOT NULL purchase in the results? The purchase column holds a string such as "Pencil" or "Paper". There is a chance the first record could simply be a check in and contain NULL for purchase.

Comment: Changed after you comments. There are two queries that will give you the first and last dates not null. The diffference between them is what you are counting. Do you want to count all the duplicates or just the not null ones each day?

Comment: there are other fields that are being SUM() in this collection. If I add the WHERE purchase is not null. I will lose accurate totals.

Comment: Then use the second query that has no where clause

Comment: OK, bear with me here. Can you change your answer to return the purchased column of the Min(Date) and Max(Date)?

Comment: Sure. But i am on mobile right now. I will do it in a while. But you will have to join the table Itself twice to get this values

Comment: I have changed the query based on your last comments. The query now get the first and last purchased items.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT nameid,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10) AS dt,
       min(case when purchase is not null then mdatetime else null end) as first_purch,
       max(case when purchase is not null then mdatetime else null end) as last_purch
  FROM employee
 GROUP BY nameid, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10)
having sum(case when purchase is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 1
```

If you also want to have the item that was purchased (for both the first and last), you can run the following:

```
with sub as(
SELECT nameid,
       CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10) AS dt,
       min(case when purchase is not null then mdatetime else null end) as first_purch,
       max(case when purchase is not null then mdatetime else null end) as last_purch
  FROM employee
 GROUP BY nameid, CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), mdatetime, 10)
having sum(case when purchase is not null then 1 else 0 end) > 1
)
select  s.nameid,
        s.dt,
        s.first_purch,
        f.purchase as first_purch_item,
        s.last_purch,
        l.purchase as last_purch_item
from sub s join employee f on s.nameid = f.nameid and s.first_purch = f.mdatetime
           join employee l on s.nameid = l.nameid and s.last_purch = l.mdatetime
```

Comment: Unfortunately the mDateTime column contains a value even if no purchase is made.

Comment: Right, but you said one of the fields is null if no purchase is made. Which field is that?

Comment: Okay, so I changed it to "where purchase is not null". Does that work for you?

Comment: I am using SUM() on each group to total other fields. I can not use where Purchase is Not NULL or else I will lose accurate totals of these groups.

Comment: @CCorock there is more to it than just adding that column to the select list (but yes, I will) however can you confirm that the data is at least correct? if it is I'll change it to show the purchase field value associated with the first and last

Comment: @CCorock I just added a query that will show the value in the purchase field for both the first and last purchase identified in each day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57711/discussion-between-brian-demilia-and-ccorock).